# Cannot backup app via Astro - (private) app?

Tags: 2.2-froyo, backup, astro-file-manager

I was just about to backup an Android application via Astro app, when I saw that there is no checkbox in the right side, but just a title saying (private).

What does it mean? How can someone restrict an app to be backed up? Is there a way to backup the app anyway?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Private means you can't back it up. The developer decided that.

Some apps ignore it

- FileExpert <- my favourite
- EStrongs File Explorer

Not a file manager, but also Titanium backup